# libjpeg: jpeg_read_scanlines rsulting buffer content clarification

Tags: c++, libjpeg

When using libjpeg to read the image lines I am using jpeg_read_scanlines as described in the sample.

The documentation describes, that for example a in image with 3 colors and a width of 100 would have to have a buffer for 300 entries that are unsigned char.
Then the content should be 1st Byte Red value, 2nd byte Green value, 3rd byte Blue value for the first pixel and then repeating for the next pixel.

In my code I am trying to "list" all of the pixels for each line, but only get a value in the first item, even though my test-image has for each line 10 pixels red, 10 pixels green, 10 pixels blue, etc...

```
row_stride = jpginfo.output_width * jpginfo.output_components;
buffer = (*jpginfo.mem->alloc_sarray)
    ((j_common_ptr) &jpginfo, JPOOL_IMAGE, row_stride, 1);

for (j=0;j<jpginfo.output_height;j++)       
  {
   jpeg_read_scanlines(&jpginfo, buffer, 1);
   for (i=0;i<row_stride;i++)
      {printf("%d, %d: %X|", j, i, buffer[i]);
      };
 };
```

The output from my code is like this:

0, 0: D4D860|0, 1: 0|0, 2: 0|0, 3: 0|0, 4: 0|0, 5: 0|0, 6: 0|0, 7: 0|0, 8: 0|0, 9: 0|0, 10: 0|0, 11: 0|0, 12: 0|0, 13: 0|0, 14: 0

Am I misinterpreting the content of the buffer content?
I would have expected the following for the red section:

0, 0: 255|0, 1: 0|0, 2: 0|0, 3: 255|0, 4: 0|0, 5: 0|

And after 10 pixel when the green starts this:

0, 10: 0|0, 11: 255|0, 12: 0|0, 13: 0|0, 14: 255|0, 15: 0|

Does anybody know what I am interpreting wrong, or needs to be set differently to get this result?
Thank you!